# iOS 5 how to record FLAC or encode from CAFF to FLAC

Tags: iphone, ios, encoding

I firstly tried FFMPEG to encode CAFF to FLAC but iOS SDK have no NSTask in it. I heard that there is another way to convert CAFF to FLAC using libFlac, I have found correct libflac.a in scumvm project but I have completely no samples of using libflac. Could someone please give me some help?

Comment: just jailbreak and get ffmpeg and then use system commands

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, but this is a solution for everyone who's trying to encode a FLAC audio file. Here's a tutorial about speech recognition on iPhone, where the aim is to record a Wave audio file and convert it to FLAC using libFlac.a

http://8byte8.com/blog/2012/07/voice-recognition-ios/

Hope that it'll help ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few small examples on how to use libflac with C or C++ here :

http://flac.cvs.sourceforge.net/flac/flac/examples/

I think There used to be an example about encoding/decoding media.

Hope this can help.